# How do I set a standard button reaction every-time a custom button is pressed down?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I've created a custom button and I'd like its background to change slightly every-time it is pressed down (anywhere within the app).

I know how to do this within each view controller with `#selector(self.cardPressed(sender:)), for: .touchDown` but I want to be able to set this within my CustomButton class so I don't need to call it again.

I tried using a didSet on the CustomButton class but I was only able to override isHighlighted and couldn't figure out how to override a variable that would look something like isNoLongerHighlighted.

```
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 5.2**

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Set the unselected background color
        backgroundColor = .red
    }

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? .green : .red
        } 
    }
}
```

[image]